# Creating a multi-dimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to create a multi-dimensional array in the format as:

```
var sizes = [
        "p" = ["1em", "2em", "3em"],
        "h1" = ["2em", "3em", "4em"]
];
```

After, I can them loop through sizes and get the array elements for each element....

How is this achievable, tried many ways just doesn't seem to be working.
Regards

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: COuld you show in your question how are you trying that?

Comment: try array of objects. or array of arrays. same outcome.

Comment: U can get help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Seems like you want an object, not an array.

Comment: Is that valid Java?  It isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: what invalidation you speak of

Comment: Learn the syntax first. Read a basic example.

Answer (score 1):

You can create like this:

```
var sizes = [
        {"p" : ["1em", "2em", "3em"]},
        {"h1" : ["2em", "3em", "4em"]},
        {"h1" : ["2em", "3em", "4em"]}
];
```

and you can access it like this:

```
$(sizes).each(function(index,element){

    element["p"];
   // in element you will find each {}
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is supported on latest version of all major browsers. No need for JQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
var sizes = []
sizes["p"] = ["1em", "2em", "3em"];
sizes["h1"] = ["2em", "3em", "4em"];

for (var k in sizes)
   for (var p in sizes[k])
       alert(sizes[k][p])
```

Comment: too much of a static approach.

Comment: Please add details so others can learn from your example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you want an array, you want an object.

```
var sizes = {
    p : ["1em", "2em", "3em"],
    h1 : ["2em", "3em", "4em"]
};
```

Now you can access it with dot notation.

```
console.log(sizes.p);
console.log(sizes.p[1]);
```

Than you can just loop over the array

```
sizes.p.forEach( function(size) {
    console.log(size);
});
```